# Как посмотреть, кто добавил репутацию за ответ/вопрос?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, голоса-за

Как посмотреть, кто добавил репутацию за ответ/вопрос?
Я сколько пользуюсь, так и не могу найти где это.

Например, я ответил на свой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/571914/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5-yii2?answertab=votes#tab-top) .
Как мне узнать, кто мне добавил рейтинг [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никак. Так задумано.

Comment: Я думал можно как-то глянуть

Comment: Можно. Трудитесь так сильно, чтоб накопить большой опыт, знания и попробуйте претендовать на место админа ресурса и тогда всё сможете посмотреть)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский стал админом только лишь для того, чтобы посмотреть кто плюсанул ответ.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский модераторы не могут, видят только сотрудники, и только не на своих вопросах и ответах.

Comment: @NickVolynkin так я и не говорю про модераторов %)

Comment: Было бы неплохо ввести такую фичу: "Алексей Шиманский получил 100k репутации и перешёл на следующий уровень. Доступные возможности: смотреть кто плюсанул ответ"

Comment: @AK на 100k репутации наверное уже знаешь всех своих голосующих )

Comment: @NickVolynkin надо у VladD поинтересоваться

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Вы не можете узнать, кто голосовал за ваши вопросы или ответы. Аналогичным образом, другие участники не могут видеть, что вы проголосовали за или против их сообщения.

Это сделано намеренно и останется так, надеюсь, навсегда.

Исключение составляют сотрудники компании, которые для целей отладки кода и поддержания порядка могут видеть раскладку голосов на чужих (но не на своих) вопросах и ответах. А могут и не видеть, это зависит от должности. Кстати, не нужно просить их посмотреть и рассказать вам — не расскажут. Модераторы не являются сотрудниками и не видят раскладку голосов.

Comment: _Кстати, не нужно просить их посмотреть и рассказать вам — не расскажут._ - просто нужно добавить побольше тега [tag:нытье] [tag:нытье] [tag:нытье] [tag:нытье] [tag:нытье] [tag:нытье] [tag:нытье]    [tag:нытье]  [tag:нытье] [tag:нытье] [tag:нытье]